# Match and do the same function block except for a type

Tags: rust, repeat

I need to do the same operations as in `Some(Md5Sess)`, changing only the type that calls `digest`. So change from `<md5::Md5>::digest` to `<sha2::Sha256>::digest` etc and possibly many others:

```
match challenge.algorithm {
    Some(Md5Sess) => {
        //I need to repeat this entire block, only changing the `md5::Md5` 
        //by the correct hashing function
        let a1_part1 =
            <md5::Md5>::digest(format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
        let cnonce = match cnonce {
            Some(cnonce) => cnonce,
            None => return Err(DigestError::MissingCNonce),
        };
        let a1_part2 = format!("{}:{}", nonce, cnonce);
        a1 = format!("{:x}:{}", a1_part1, a1_part2);
        let entity_body = match &body {
            Some(body) => body.as_ref(),
            None => "".as_bytes(),
        };
        hash_common::<md5::Md5>(
            method,
            chosen_qop,
            a1,
            nonce,
            Some(cnonce),
            nonce_count,
            uri,
            body,
        )
    }
    Some(Sha512Trunc256Sess) => 
        Err(DigestError::DigestAlgorithmNotImplemented(Sha512Trunc256Sess)),
    Some(Sha256Sess) => 
        Err(DigestError::DigestAlgorithmNotImplemented(Sha256Sess)),
    Some(Algorithm::Other(s)) => 
        Err(DigestError::DigestAlgorithmNotImplemented(Algorithm::Other(s))),
}
```

My only idea is to create a function that is generic on the type of the hash, with the inconvenient of having lots of arguments, for each variable used in that block.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

I tried with macros too, only to remember that in Rust, macros are not like in C where they don't care about the text being used. I did a macro that matched by the type of the hash like my_macro!(md5::Md5) but then it complained about the variables being used in the block.

Comment: What is `hash_common`, and why does it take the algorithm as a type parameter?

Comment: @LambdaFairy it's another function that does some common things used by all blocks. I see that you think I can just put my block inside hash_function, but this is not possible. This block is just for `HashSess` cases of the match. I hid the non sess cases because they just call `hash_common` directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do it by first selecting the functions to apply, then manipulating the data:

```
// Select the functions to apply
let (digest, common) = match challenge.algorithm {
    Some (Md5Sess) => (<md5::Md5>::digest, hash_common::<md5::Md5>),
    Some (Sha256Sess) => (<sha2::Sha256>::digest, hash_common::<sha2::Sha256>),
    _ => todo!(),
}

// Now process the data
let a1_part1 = digest (format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
let cnonce = match cnonce {
    Some(cnonce) => cnonce,
    None => return Err (DigestError::MissingCNonce)
};
let a1_part2 = format!("{}:{}", nonce, cnonce);
a1 = format!("{:x}:{}", a1_part1, a1_part2);
let entity_body = match &body {
    Some (body) => body.as_ref(),
    None => "".as_bytes()
};
common (method, chosen_qop, a1, nonce, Some (cnonce), nonce_count, uri, body)
```

Comment: this is a good ifea. Unfortunately I've hid some cases. There are `HashSess` cases, where this block of code apply, but there are `Hash` cases, for which the block does not apply. Do you know of an elegant solution to apply the block for `HashSess` and another block for `Hash`?

Comment: If you want to enable or disable parts of the processing, you can have the match return `Option` instead of straight function then `if let` to apply or not each part.

Comment: Unfortunately this doers not work: `Some (Sha256Sess) => (<sha2::Sha256>::digest, hash_common::<sha2::Sha256>),
    | |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `md5::Md5`, found struct `sha2::Sha2`. Full error: https://pastebin.com/TryKVucK

Comment: The output of the `fn` has an internal type called `Output`. This internal type changes according to the hash function. So these functions cannot be all of the same type, as demanded by the `match`

Comment: Then you can wrap the function in a closure that unifies the return type: `|s| <md5::Md5>::digest (s).as_bytes()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, closures are not equal even if they accept and return the same things: `note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type`

Comment: Closures with the same parameters and return types [can be chosen with a `match`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=deb7b3ba082feb1cb2a51b818903be4b). The problem here is that different digests may return arrays of different lengths, so you will need to convert the digest to string in the closures.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not claim this is the best solution, as I would probably prefer using a function if at all possible, but if that is out of the question, here goes:

The [duplicate](https://crates.io/crates/duplicate) can help you reuse your block in all the match cases:

```rust
use duplicate::duplicate:

duplicate! {
    [
        func(hash_type);
        [
            //I need to repeat this entire block, only changing the `md5::Md5` by the correct hashing function
            let a1_part1 = <hash_type>::digest(format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
            let cnonce = match cnonce {
                Some(cnonce) => cnonce,
                None => return Err(DigestError::MissingCNonce)
            };
            let a1_part2 = format!("{}:{}", nonce, cnonce);
            a1 = format!("{:x}:{}", a1_part1, a1_part2);
            let entity_body = match &body {
                Some(body) => body.as_ref(),
                None => "".as_bytes()
            };
            hash_common::<hash_type>(method, chosen_qop, a1, nonce, Some(cnonce), nonce_count, uri, body)
        ];
    ]
    match challenge.algorithm {
        Some(Md5Sess) => {
            func([md5::Md5]) // Duplicates the block with hash_type = md5::Md5
        },
        Some(Sha512Trunc256Sess) => {
            func([sha2::Sha256])// Duplicates the block with hash_type = sha2::Sha256
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

This will repeat the function body (which has been out of the its original block and into a substitution) in each match case, replacing `hash_type` with the hash type you provide in `func([md5::Md5])`, `func([sha2::Sha256])`, etc.